# using PIL in asynchronous code (Twisted Web)

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, python-imaging-library

I have a web API which receives an image, and passes it to another asynchronous service. However before passing if further I scale it down using PIL.

My code looks something like that (simplifying, skipping unrelated details):

```
def render_POST(self, request):
    pil_image = Image.open(request.content)
    pil_image.thumbnail((640,640), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
    outfile = StringIO()
    pil_image.save(outfile, "JPEG")
    do_something_async_and_write_result(outfile)
    return NOT_DONE_YET
```

Is there a way I can make it asynchronous without over-engineering* it?

**I would consider for example setting up a message queue service just for that over-engineering*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If thread saftey is given (concerning PIL and how you use it), you could use deferToThread:
https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.html

Enhanced formulation, thanks Calderone

Comment: Thread safety is always a concern when using threads!  I think what you mean is "If PIL is thread-safe, ...". :)

Comment: Your question is kind of hard to answer then.

Comment: What is "over" engineering?  If you don't have another solution that meets your desired specifications, then it seems like exactly the right amount of engineering.